# Replacing radio buttons with individual images including hover and selected ... nearly there

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

We are trying to replace a set of four radio buttons with a set of four images, each with its own hover and selected image.

We have sent the radio button off screen using CSS, created the main images to show as the label and also set the hover, but we are experiencing issues with the Javascript/jQuery we are using which adds a 'selected' class to the buttons. It works for the first button, but I am lost on how to replicate this for the other three - your advice on this would be very much appreciated.

The JS Fiddle for this can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/HVk7d/8/

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is and what you mean by "it works for the first button ... but lost on how to replicate". Replicate what? It seems to do something in FF12 on all four.

Comment: Again, I've found that it works fine in Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it working in the end - here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/HVk7d/18/
All the best,

Matthew

Comment: What? No diagnosis, no description of the foible at hand, no... Nothing? Just a link?

Comment: @JaredFarrish he *did* link us to a fiddle at very least...

Netwise, congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark the most helpful answer as 'accepted' (even if it is your own) so that others will be able to learn from your success.  Cheers~